# Error importing python module made by pybind11

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I followed the steps in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5T70cAXDJ0), and was able to successfully import a python module made by pybind11 and call the function `add()`. When I try to refactor my code and move the `add()` function to a separate file, I get the following error message:

```
>>> import pybindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user_name/Desktop/project/build/pybindings.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (__Z3addii)
```

This is my cpp file:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

#include "refactored_code.hpp" //this contains the add() function

PYBIND11_MODULE(pybindings, m) {
  m.doc() = "test of pybind11";

  m.def("add", &add, "adds two numbers");
}
```

and this is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(test_project)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(pybindings pybindings.cpp)
```

I'd appreciate any help since I'm very new to this. Thank you!

Comment: You don't really have the code in the `.hpp`, do you?  Do you just have the declaration in the .hpp and the code in a `.cpp`?  If so, then you need to add `refactored_code.cpp` to your build.

Comment: show the content of your refactored_code.hpp and refactored_code.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Turn on all compiler warnings and errors

```
-pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
```

Second: Can you show the definition you have of the `add()` function?

Third: Does your refactored_code.hpp have a cpp file? You need to list it along with your pybindings.cpp file in here:

```
pybind11_add_module(pybindings pybindings.cpp refactored_code.cpp) // Notice the "cpp" not "hpp"
```

Undefined symbol means that you had the header but did not link in the actual implementation. There are *some* legitimate reasons to do this but it's almost never right to not link it in directly like this.

Comment: Adding refactored_code.cpp to the pybind11_add_module resolved the issue, thank you! Can you give me an intuition as to why adding that cpp file is necessary, given that I had already included its header file?

Comment: Yes. It has to do with how C++ links. You can compile with nothing but prototypes in a header (or wherever). The symbols in the header tell the compiler that you promise to add those symbols in before you use them. In order to link properly you have to have the implementations available. There are a few different ways to link. The main ones are static and dynamic. Static is what you are doing. Just add it in the compile line. This means that the connection is made once at build/link time. When using dynamic linking the symbol implementation is brought in at runtime, hence the "dynamic".